# Neovim - Closing buffers/panes like Ag leaves trail of it behind

Tags: macos, vim, neovim, iterm

I am using NeoVim in iTerm. Whenever I open any temporary panes like `Ag` to search for some text in my project, after selecting an occurrence from the list, I notice it leaving some parts of the old buffer left behind. (screenshot attached)[image] It gets fixed when I navigate through the entire affected area of the buffer using j,k or Up,Down.

My vimrc: https://github.com/AvinashKrSharma/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: updating to latest neovim version fixed the problem